# Yup validation array items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have a text field area. Users can add extra fields. I can take all values from these fields and put them into a single array. But I don't want to send to backend empty string.  I am using YUP as a validation

For instance;

```
Field 1 = "hi"
Field 2 = "how"
Field 3 = ""

const myArray = ["hi","how",""]

to be sent = ["hi","how"]
```

If I have only one item like

```
Field 1 = ""
```

I want to say = `"this field can not be blank"`

What I did

```
 array()
        .compact(v => Boolean(v) !== true)
        .required("Can not be blank"),
```